# Trying to use a ViewModel on a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

So I'm editing the default ASP.NET MVC with authentication template, and I'm trying to create a ViewModel for `_PartialLogin.cshtml` in order to display a name instead of the user's e-mail. I searched a lot of things, but they were pretty outdated so I hope someone can help. I don't even know if creating a ViewModel is the best option.

Here's the `LoginPartialViewModel`:

```
namespace AplicacaoRoles2.Models.SharedViewModels
{
    public class PartialLoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`_LoginPartial.cshtml`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using AplicacaoRoles2.Models

@model AplicacaoRoles2.Models.SharedViewModels.PartialLoginViewModel

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome) !</a>
            </li>
```

(...)
`HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        PartialLoginViewModel model = new PartialLoginViewModel();
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var applicationUser = await _context.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserName == userName);

        model.Nome = applicationUser.Nome;

        return View(model);
    }
```

On `_Layout.cshtml` there's this portion useful:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

(the code is simplified to shorted this)

So this is working fine while I'm on `Home/index` because it as no Model, but as soon as I enter a page with a model it shows an model error thing.

I could replace:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

for

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new AplicacaoRoles2.Models.SharedViewModels.PartialLoginViewModel())
```

But the problem is that I lose the information by creating a new instance...
Thank you.

**Some words like 'Nome' are not misspelled, they are in portuguese

Comment: if you return this `new AplicacaoRoles2.Models.SharedViewModels.PartialLoginViewModel()`, you will always get a empty model because you returning a newly creating empty instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first see what the issue is that your are running into and then we will apply a fix.

**The Issue/Problem**

The `_LoginPartial.cshtml` is called from the `Shared/_Layout.cshtml` unless you have changed it; it seems you have not changed it so it is using the defaults. That is fine, you do not have to change it. When you visit `Home/Index`, you create an instance of `PartialLoginViewModel` and pass it to the `Home/Index.cshtml`. By default, all `.cshtml` files use `Shared/_Layout.cshtml` so essentially this is how your `PartialLoginViewModel` is being passed around:

Home/Index (Controller) **=>** Home/Index.cshtml **=>** Shared/_Layout.cshtml 
    **=>** _LoginPartial.cshtml

So in the above, it is pretty clear that `_LoginPartial.cshtml` eventually gets a hold of `PartialLoginViewModel` and that is why it works when you visit `Home/Index`. All good and dandy :)

Now let's see what happens when you visit another page; say `SomeController.SomeAction`. Let's further imagine the other page has a model of type `SomeModel`. Here is how the `SomeModel` will be passed around:

Some/SomeAction (Controller) **=>** Some/SomeAction.cshtml **=>** Shared/_Layout.cshtml **=>** _LoginPartial.cshtml

And boom it fails because `_LoginPartial.cshtml` is expecting a model which has the properties of `PartialLoginViewModel` but instead you have given it `SomeModel`.

**Not a Fix**

This will not work:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new AplicacaoRoles2.Models.SharedViewModels.PartialLoginViewModel())
```

because you are sending the correct model (PartialLoginViewModel) to the `_LoginPartial` but it is a new instance and the properties have not been set. Therefore, the `Name` (you spelled it `Nome`) will be empty.

This will also not work:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", Model)
```

because you are sending it the model from your main view which is of a different type.

**Fix**

One way to fix your issue is to inherit all your models for your views (view models) from `PartialLoginViewModel` so the partial stays happy.

```
public class PartialLoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class SomeModel : PartialLoginViewModel
{
    // Code ...
}
```

You would also need to populate the `Name` property in all your controller actions. So simply create a base class and inherit all your controllers from that. Like this:

```
public class CustomController : Controller
{
    protected virtual async Task<TModel> CreateModel<TModel>() where TModel : PartialLoginViewModel, new()
    {
        TModel model = new TModel();
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var applicationUser = await _context.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserName == userName);

        // Set common properties
        model.Nome = applicationUser.Nome;

        return model;
    }
}
```

Then inherit all your controllers from the above controller and always call the above controller's `CreateModel` method so it can populate the common properties as shown below:

```
public class EveryoneOfYourControllers : CustomController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = await base.CreateModel<SomeModel>();

        // Set other properties on your model

        return View();
    }
}
```

All the code is in one place. In the future if you decide to add another property to `PartialLoginViewModel`, you will only need the change the code in in one place to set the additional property.

Now that you know the issue, you can come up with different solutions.

Comment: This looks like the answer, I changed a few thing on the way like:
`protected virtual async Task<TModel> CreateModel<TModel>(ApplicationDbContext context) where TModel : PartialLoginViewModel, new()`
And i think there is no problem there. But either way I cant use any model I want on:
`var modelFor = await base.CreateModel<IndexViewModel>(_context);`
It says I cant convert `IndexViewModel` into `PartialLoginViewModel` Thank you for your help @CodingYoshi

Comment: @leonardohenrique You did not inherit `IndexViewModel` from `PartialLoginViewModel` as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @LeonardoHenriques I also some code on how to do that.

Comment: Yes you are right. I got it working, just did some teaks and it's working now. Thank you @CodingYoshi

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the ViewModel from your View into the PartialView, so you would include the ViewModel as the Model for your Index.cshtml as well. You are already sending the ViewModel you need to your View via the Controller, so you just need to pass that model to the constructor for your Partial.

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", Model)
```

Is this ASP.NET Core MVC? If so you may be better off using a ViewComponent instead.

Comment: This will still crash and result in the same error which the OP is having. Simply passing the model into the partial will not work. See my answer below please.

Comment: Yes, this won't work, I've tried. I also tried ViewComponets aswell, but I couldn't get it work either so... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Option One:**

Since you're passing the PartialLoginViewModel as the main model for the index of Home, the index of Home view should also include this line below as the model:

```
@model AplicacaoRoles2.Models.SharedViewModels.PartialLoginViewModel
```

If this is the case, you can simply pass in the page's 'Model' object into any views within the Home.cshtml view:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", Model)
```

The model here should represent the model passed in from the HomeController.cs, containing the user's nome.

**Option Two**:

Another option is to use ViewData's.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        PartialLoginViewModel model = new PartialLoginViewModel();
        var userName = User.Identity.Name;
        var applicationUser = await _context.ApplicationUser.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserName == userName);

        model.Nome = applicationUser.Nome;
        ViewData["userModel"] = model;

        return View();
    }
```

And the use this line to import model:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", ViewData["userModel"])
```

Comment: This will not solve the issue. Actually you are essentially doing something the OP is already doing but in a different way and this way is not as good as the OPs way. This will not solve anything. The OP is not having any issues when visiting `Home/Index`.